# After trying to Install Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus 10 the device won't turn on

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-10

the only reaction the device shows is the charging symbol, when i connect it to my pc.
No magic button pressing or something else helped. Is there anything i can do to bring it to life again?

i think it is dead.

thanks for helping.
Uwe

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot to the bootloader by both volume buttons and power button?

If yes, try boot to recovery by menu in booloader.

If you can go to recovery, then is easy flash original Android ROM.

Or you can post tutorial which you follow at installation?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering but i cant boot to the bootloader. Seems that everything is wiped out. adp is not recognizing the device at all.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and it seems to be two problems:
1. Nexus 10 problem
2. Ubuntu Touch Install problem

=> 1.: Nexus 10 seems to sometimes do this, when the battery is very empty. Try to recharge it. Try to press the Start button for about 30sec. With recharging I could move on and get to Problem 2. 
More Infos I found here: http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-10-tablet/248372-nexus-10-wont-turn.html

For Problem 2 I also still need a solution, but I guess this is not the topic here.